# WIFI scan without results Ubuntu 16.04 dualboot on Mac

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, broadcom

I'm new to Ubuntu: I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in dual boot on my mid-2010 MacBook Pro.The installation seems to have gone smoothly, however I have a problem with the wifi, since my wifi card doesn't find any wifi when scanning. I have already checked and installed the bcmwl-kernel-source that according to many other questions and websites(also the Ubuntu hel page) is the necessary driver for the Wifi card I have on, but still nothing has changed and after 2 days og writing lots of things in the shell to try and resolve this problem on my own without any success I though I'd come and ask.

Here you find the output of the wireless info script. I though might be useful to explain myself better http://pastebin.com/DGGCAtT3

Comment: What is the output of `iwconfig` command?

Comment: The script results you posted show the WiFi is correctly installed (correct driver) and it lists several networks and is connected to one, "CASA-FADY". What is your problem exactly?

Comment: It could be wifi power management causing issues with wl, so try `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` and reboot

Answer (score 0):

You and I have the same wifi Card.  It is a BCM4322 pci ID 14e4:432b.

According to this chart, you can try a different driver.  I personally use sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms instead of bcmwl-kernel-source even though they both install wl (prop driver).

You can see from this chart our card also is partially supported by b43 which is kernel agnostic.

http://linuxwireless.org/en/users/Drivers/b43/#Supported_devices

If you are not having luck with b43, i'd suggest reinstalling bcmwl kernel source or broadcom-sta-dkms (after purging or blacklisting b43 it).

"
**Here is how to switch drivers (copied from linuxwireless.org):**

Switching between drivers

If you have few drivers installed, system may auto-load different driver than the one you wanted to use. Manual (un)loading drivers can be done with modprobe tool.

To unload all known drivers (you can pick only one command, if you know which driver is in use) perform:

```
Toggle line numbers

   1 modprobe -r b43 bcma
   2 modprobe -r brcmsmac bcma
   3 modprobe -r wl
```

To load specific driver use one of the following commands:

```
Toggle line numbers

   1 modprobe b43
   2 modprobe brcmsmac
   3 modprobe wl
```

It is possible to prevent system from auto-loading some drivers by blacklisting them. This can be done with the following command:

```
Toggle line numbers

   1 echo "blacklist drivername" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist
```

If you plan to use wl, you should blacklist b43 and brcmsmac as well as bcma. Unfortunately wl does not use bcma bus driver, so this additional step is required. "